# Socket.emit not working Nodejs Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am just trying to send a simple message from client to server on button Click.

**Edit:**
When my index.jade loads I use the following code and for creating the socket.io object and then forward it to my `Menu_Contoller` which in turn assigns the socket object to the `Menu_Model`.Then whenever the function `SendOptionSelectedToServer`  of `Menu_Model.js` is called i use the socket object to of `Menu_Model`.The values in this function are correct.Just don't know why it is not `emitting`.

**index.jade**

```
script(src = '/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(src = '/javascripts/Menu_Controller.js')
script(src = '/javascripts/Menu_Model.js')

script

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.emit('GameType','chutia');

var Menu_Control = Object.create(Menu_Controller);

Menu_Control.Init(socket);
```

**Menu_Controller.js**

```
   var Menu_Controller = {

    Model : null,

    Init:function(socket)
    {
        this.Model = Object.create(Menu_Model);
        this.Model.Init(socket,this);
    },
    SendOptionSelectedToServer:function(option)    <-- called from a view menu which we don't have to care about because value in 'option' are correct.
    {
        this.Model.SendOptionSelectedToServer(option);
    }

};
```

**Menu_Model.js**

```
 var Menu_Model = {
    Socket     : null,
    Controller : null,

    Init:function(sock,controllerRef)
    {
        this.Socket = sock;
        this.Controller = controllerRef;
    },
    SendOptionSelectedToServer:function(option)
    {
        this.Socket.emit(option.type,option.ghostName);       <-- this line.
    }
};
```

And here's my complete server side code in **app.js**.

```
var express = require('express')
  , http    = require('http')
  , routes  = require('./routes')
  , io      = require('socket.io')
  , factory = require('./serverfactory.js');
var  app  = express();

var server = app.listen(3000);
io = io.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

console.log('new user');                        <-- this is printed in the log.

socket.on('GameType',function(msg){
    console.log(msg);                           <-- but this is not.
});
});



//var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

When a new connection occurs it writes `new user` in the log.But when a call is made using `emit` from the client side it doesn't write any msg in the console.I've already checked the params at the client side and they are correct. the `option.type` at the client side will contain `GameType`.

Why it is not calling the event on the client side ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing option.type with 'GameType' just to see if that works?

Comment: I recommend you to put a break point to trace application instead of working with `console.log`.

Comment: @jaykreeler I already tried that but still doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, it's likely that your emit isn't even being called; are you using firebug/an equivalent debugging program? If so, are there any errors being displayed?

Comment: I am using chrome. But it is not showing any errors.

Comment: Can you show where in your code you called "Menu.SendOptionSelectedToServer"?

Comment: this function is called correctly and the `option.type` and `option.ghostName` has correct values.I am editing question to give you guys more details.I hope you guys can help after that.I think I've not provided enough details.

Comment: i have exactly the same problem/behavior. did you solved it somehow?